# Looking for suggestions to split a row in R df into multiple rows

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a dataframe with the structure below.

```
df <- data.frame(x = c(1,9), y = c(2,9), z = c(4,9), id_1 = c(5,2), id_2 = c(6,3), id_3 = c(8,7), d1 = c(7,44), d2 = c(8,55), d3 = c(0,76), d4 = c(8,0))
```

This is my final expected output

```
df_out <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,1,9,9,9), y = c(2,2,2,9,9,9), z = c(4,4,4,9,9,9), id = c(5,6,8,2,3,7), d1 = c(7,7,7,44,44,44), d2 = c(8,8,8,55,55,55), d3 = c(0,0,0,76,76,76), d4 = c(8,8,8,0,0,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
> library(dplyr)
> library(tidyr)
> df %>% pivot_longer(cols = c(id_1,id_2,id_3), values_to = 'id') %>% select(-name) %>% relocate(1:3,8,4:7)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
      x     y     z    id    d1    d2    d3    d4
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     2     4     5     7     8     0     8
2     1     2     4     6     7     8     0     8
3     1     2     4     8     7     8     0     8
4     9     9     9     2    44    55    76     0
5     9     9     9     3    44    55    76     0
6     9     9     9     7    44    55    76     0
>
```

Data used:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(x = c(1, 9), y = c(2, 9), z = c(4, 9), id_1 = c(5, 
2), id_2 = c(6, 3), id_3 = c(8, 7), d1 = c(7, 44), d2 = c(8, 
55), d3 = c(0, 76), d4 = c(8, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Hi, I cant see the new column "id" created.

Comment: It's there last column.

Comment: @SuprabhathKalahasti, I've arranged columns as per your expected output, please check now.

Comment: Hi @Karthik, thanks a lot for your help. In my dataset, the id columns are in different positions and not in actual sequence as I shared. Hence I wound up specifying the column names in a vector as c(id1, id2, id3). Does this change anything in the context of the code. After running your code, I still get the same dataframe with the same number of rows and columns? Kindly advise

Comment: @SuprabhathKalahasti, have modified the query, can you please check now

Comment: @SuprabhathKalahasti, If it worked, can you please mark my code as answered using the "tick" mark next to my answer